# Given a finite set of points construct a polynomial that meets the points.

Tags: polynomials, boolean-algebra, interpolation

Say I have a set of points in $\mathbb{Z}^3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ each of which represent part of a mapping $(z_1, z_2, z_3) \mapsto z_4 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.  How do I find the the simplest polynomial function such that the restriction to the above set of given points $\{(z_1,z_2,z_3)\}$ is equal to the given mapping.  I.e. for all $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)\in \mathbb{Z}^3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, $ \ f(z_1,z_2,z_3) = z_4$?

Please see a related [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504535/the-set-of-all-polynomial-functions-from-mathbbz3-rightarrow-mathbbz-2)

I think you can take the set of points and modulo the coordinates by $2$ since the polynomials will be evaluated mod $2$ and taking an integer modulo $2$ is a homomorphism and distributes through the polynomial using the homomorphism.  Then you have a table of inputs and outputs:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
(z_1, & z_2, & z_3)& \rightarrow & z_4 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow &0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow &1 \\
{\vdots} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow &1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow &1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

of mappings that is finite.  Somehow you then turn this into a Boolean function in normal form, but forgot how.